# SSIS transforming numbers with decimal comma to decimal dot

Tags: ssis, visual-studio

I'm trying to create a very basic package that copies data from my SQL server into an Excel file.

The data that comes from the server comes with a decimal comma (e.g. 1234,56) - that is how I want it, that is how it's always worked, that is how I want the final data to be formatted in Excel.
For some reason Visual Studio / SSIS is *always* transforming this data to a decimal point format (e.g. 1234.56) - that's not how I want it, I can't work with that.

I've tried every form of data conversion, doesn't matter if it's DT_NUMERIC, DT_DECIMAL, DT_CY, it's always giving me a decimal dot - even when going the Derived Column route, specifically turning the values into DT_WSTR, then replacing every "." with a "," and then converting to any numerical format still gives me a result with decimal points.

The problem is that Visual studio is previewing the SQL input in the correct formats, the numbers *do* have a decimal comma, the input is 100% correct - but at some point the comma is being transformed into a period without my doing. [image]

The Excel Connection Manager's LocalID setting is set to German, so it should produce correctly formatted numbers. I tried pre-formatting the Excel-Destination file's columns to my desired format - not working. I tried putting in correctly formatted dummy data into the Excel-File and set it to Overwrite - not working.

Kinda losing my mind here, anyone got any clue on what's causing this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, always worth checking the consumer for *rendering issues*. In this case, when Excel's involved and it's a formatting issue, you can never be too careful to verify that Excel isn't the source of the problem.

Sometimes changing the **Format** option for that column in Excel to "Default" or "Text" reveals the original formatting. Though I've had my fair share of issues with Excel still being wonky with how it was formatting my data even then.

Best way to check, when it's a CSV, is to just open the file in a plain text editor and verify the raw data is formatted as expected. Excel seemed to be the issue in your case.

Comment: Excel was indeed the problem. Is there any known fix as to what is causing this problem with Excel? Even when trying to convert the CSV to XLSX it's causing the same , <-> , issues. I mean, CSV's are definitely workable, but for end user firendliness a proper Excel solution would be just that extra little bit more convenient.

Comment: @PeterParker Unfortunately I don't think there's much control you have if you're initially generating the file as a CSV. Excel has its own built in logic to handle how it auto-formats data. Though you might have more luck asking this question on a more relevant StackExchange board to Excel like SuperUser, for potential solutions, since this is no longer a database related issue.